# Adding a button at the very end of content div is causing a vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where adding a button at the end of a div is causing a vertical scrollbar to appear. If I add content after the button then it doesn't. I haven't been able to figure out why this occurs. In my html I have:

`<span class='cta'><a href='#' class='cta'>View More Information</a></span>`

That is inside of my content div. The CSS I've got going is:

```
.content {
overflow: auto;
margin-left: 180px; }

span.cta {
background-color: rgba(102, 153, 204, 1);
padding: 6px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 10px;
display: inline; }

a.cta {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none; }
```

If I use this style as the last item in my `.content` then I get a vertical scrollbar. If I add an empty element like a row or paragraph with `&nbsp;` after it then it doesn't create the vertical scrollbar. I've tried playing with `display` `height` `margin` and haven't been able to figure out what's causing the problem.

Comment: unless you have a fixed height parent it shouldn't be adding a scrollbar. One thing you can try is {overflow:inherit;}

Comment: @peterchon When I do overflow inherit it messes up my navigation, so my navigation no longer extends to the top of the page.

Comment: btw, any specific reason why you're wrapping a <a> tag inside a <span> with a same class name?

Comment: @peterchon hmm probably not. Most of the tutorials I've read on css links/buttons use a div/a combo so thats what I did.